# Hide the UI and take a screenshot with one key press

Tags: world-of-warcraft, windows

In World of Warcraft there is a screen shot feature that is assigned to the print screen key by default.

When I take screenshots, I like to hide the user interface by pressing alt + z and then pressing the print screen key to take a screenshot.

The problem with this is that by the time I've pressed alt + z and then pressed the print screen key, the thing I wanted to take a screenshot of is often different or not there any more.

What do I need to do to get the same effect as pressing alt + z and then the print screen key with one key press? Can this be done with a macro, or is there something in there already that does it? I've looked through the options, but I can't find anything, maybe I missed it.

Comment: If you have a programmable keyboard you can assign a key for this sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), you can rebind the print screen button (or any other button) to first send alt+z and then send printscreen.

Something like this should work:

```
PrintScreen::
    Send, {Alt}z
    sleep, 100
    Send, {PrintScreen}
    sleep, 100
    Send, {Alt}z
```

If you are good at using AHK you could also make it so that the alt+z would only be sent if the focus is set to a World of Warcraft window. I recommend asking on either Stack Overflow or the Autohotkey forums for help on adding that functionality.

Comment: Would this be considering scripting? I know that it does not affect gameplay in a certain way, but is it possible World of Warcraft has certain rules against programs like this?

Answer (score 1):

My alt+z goes to nvidia options. However,  you can press esc. Go to your keybinds, look for it and set it to whatever button(s) you would like. I did ctrl+u (u - since I'm hiding my UI).